# Rails: saving a user field from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mongodb, controller

Combo: Rails4, Mongoid
I have an Admin console dashboard: `/admin/moderator-slug/dashboard`
that lists all users with a button to go manage that user:

```
<%= link_to "Manage", { controller: 'admin', action: 'manage', user: user} %>
```

As you can see, I pass that user in the params.
In my Admin controller, my manage action is as follows:

```
def manage
  @user = User.find(params[:user])
  if params[:follow_up].present?
    @user.follow_up = Date.strptime(params[:follow_up], "%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end
```

It successfully leads to the management page: `/admin/moderator-slug/manage?user=managed-user-slug` and finds the @user through the params I pass with the button.

In my User model I created a Time field "follow_up".

I want to update that field with a certain time selected with datepicker, so I created the following form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag manage_path, method: "get", remote: true do %>
  Follow up: <%= text_field_tag "follow_up", nil, autocomplete: "off" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

When I press the submit button I get `Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind`

When I pass on a hidden field `<%= hidden_field_tag :user , @user %>` , I get 404. And besides, I have a feeling my set up is not the healthiest, so passing on that hidden field is really a workaround that could be avoided.

my routes:

```
authenticate :user, -> (u) { u.is_moderator? } do
  match 'admin/:slug/dashboard',    to: 'admin/admin#dashboard',    via: 'get',   as: :dashboard
  match 'admin/:slug/manage',       to: 'admin/admin#manage',       via: 'get',   as: :manage
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the output from `rake routes`.

Comment: "dashboard GET      /admin/:slug/dashboard(.:format)                       admin/admin#dashboard"  and "manage GET      /admin/:slug/manage(.:format)                          admin/admin#manage"

Comment: actually I mainly wanted to see `manage_path` URL shortcut, please add all lines containing `manage_path` to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or your question

Comment: EugZol, manage_path only appears once in the view and once in routes. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/whoteaches/67c15a5cf783ce5c7fd3

Comment: So you are using the same URL (`admin/:slug/manage`) for showing form and for updating the field as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should add user slug to your form URL:

```
<%= form_tag manage_path(user: @user), method: "get", remote: true do %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing.